# Make a dock icon always open a new window in OS X?

Tags: macos, dock

In OS X (Snow Leopard), I find that for web browsers and terminals, whenever I click the dock icon, it opens the existing window, not open a new one.

Is there any way to modify the behaviour so that clicking these dock icons always opens a new window, instead of having to navigate the command-click menu?

Comment: I don't know if it's so easy to modify the default behavior, but an option would be to [create a launcher](http://i.imgur.com/CsB5N.png) that will always open a new window. Downside is, you'll have the same icon twice. Would that be a viable workaround for you?

Comment: I just installed and uninstalled LiteSwitch X (an application switcher replacement) to see if it either had an option to always open new windows (no) or if it had some shortcut or action (like ⌘N) for opening a new window (no). I'm not sure about Witch or Dock replacements. AFAIK, there's no such configuration for the standard Dock. Or any hidden modifier-click for opening a new window or anything.

Comment: @slhck I'd appreciate an answer with instructions for creating a launcher that creates new windows

Comment: @StephenOstermiller See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Open *Automator.app* and create a new *Application*.

Add the action *Run Shell Script* and paste the following contents:

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --new-window "https://google.com"
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Now save the workflow under *Chrome New Window.app* or whatever you prefer.

Drag the saved file to your Dock.

If you want to change its icon, you should:

- Find the *Google Chrome.app* file in your `/Applications` folder
- Click on it once and press `Cmd-I`
- Select the icon and copy it with `Cmd-C`
- Find the workflow you just created
- Click on it once and press `Cmd-I`
- Select the icon and paste the clipboard with `Cmd-V`
- Done